# How can i get context of an app in a fragment

Tags: android

in this moment i am making a personal exercise exactly a RSS reader. I want to get context on my app into a fragment i can't do it for some reason. I am a student of a high school so this error does not have sense for me. If someone can try to explain me that and why happens, i will be so greatful. the error is this 
`"error: incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Context"`. And the code looks like this

```
public class LectorRss extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

ArrayList<Noticia> noticias;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Context context;
String direccion = "https://actualidad.rt.com/feeds/all.rss";
URL url;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;



public LectorRss(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.context = context;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
        AdapterNoticia adapterNoticia = new AdapterNoticia(noticias, context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterNoticia);

    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    procesarXML(obtenerDatos());
    return null;
}

private void procesarXML(Document data){
    if (data != null){
        noticias = new ArrayList<>();
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < items.getLength() ; i++){
            Node hijoActual = items.item(i);
            if (hijoActual.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                Noticia  noticia = new Noticia();
                NodeList itemsChild = hijoActual.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0 ; j < itemsChild.getLength() ; j++){
                        Node actual =  itemsChild.item(j);
                        if (actual.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                            noticia.setmTitulo(actual.getTextContent());
                        }else if (actual.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                        noticia.setmEnlace(actual.getTextContent());
                    }else if (actual.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                            noticia.setmDescripcion(actual.getTextContent());
                        }else if (actual.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")){
                            String mUrl = actual.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                            noticia.setmImagen(mUrl);
                        }else if (actual.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                            noticia.setmFecha(actual.getTextContent());
                        }
                }
                noticias.add(noticia);
                Log.d("Titulo: ", noticia.getmTitulo());
                Log.d("Link: ", noticia.getmEnlace());
                Log.d("Descripcion: ", noticia.getmDescripcion());
                Log.d("Enlace de imagen: ", noticia.getmImagen());
                Log.d("Fecha: ", noticia.getmFecha());
            }
        }
    }
}

public Document obtenerDatos(){ //Este metodo obtiene los datos de la url
    try{
        url = new URL(direccion);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

this is the fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LectorRss lectorRss = new LectorRss(this, recyclerView);
    lectorRss.execute();
    return v;
}
```

Comment: just call getContext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fragment is not a valid context.  Instead, you should call either `getContext()` or `getActivity()` from the fragment.  Note that this may be null, so you should normally check that before proceeding. Here, you are calling it after getting a reference to a view, so you can use that to guarantee a context.

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
LectorRss lectorRss = new LectorRss(v.getContext(), recyclerView);
lectorRss.execute();


return v;
```

}

However, your bigger problem is the memory leak you potentially create.  You are passing in a reference to both your context and a view into an asynchronous process.  When `onPostExecute` returns, your activity may be gone from view, but you still have a reference to it via the view.  Better would be to refactor this entirely to eliminate the need for the async task to know about the view.  Look into the new Android Lifecycle components or some other sort of observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can just get the fragment context by calling `getContext()` you don't really need the app context actually  and it's better to avoid memory leakage. But if you think you need it, you can call `getContext().getApplicationContext()`

```java
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    //here call getContext()
    LectorRss lectorRss = new LectorRss(getContext(), recyclerView);
    lectorRss.execute();
```